# what is the difference between shared preferences and internal storage in Android? Where does the data stored?

Tags: android, share, android-preferences

what is the difference between shared preferences and internal storage in Android? Where does the data is stored? Looks like Android system allocates specific amount of space for each application. While using shared preferences, my app ran out of memory and threw OutOfMemory Exception. If I use internal storage to save this data into files, will this resolve the issue? If internal storage also uses the same limited allocated space for the app, then how to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes the issue will resolve

Comment: How much data are you trying to store into SharedPreferences that you would cause an OutOfMemoryException? It must be a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SharedPreferences stores data in key-value pairs. It stores them mainly in RAM but it also saves a copy to the internal storage. Android provides RAM for storing your code, all the graphics and any temporary data, and it's limited. If you store a lot of key-value pairs (and maybe the values are long `String`s), you may indeed use all the RAM for your app and end up with an `OutOfMemoryException`. That's an indication that SharedPreference is probably not the right method for the data you're trying to store.

The internal storage, instead, is entirely based on Flash memory. Apps have less constraints there, and they can store large amounts of data like images. The internal storage is kinda like a directory, so you create files, read/write on them, delete them etc., so it's different than key-value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the difference between shared preferences and internal storage in Android?

[Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) refers to a place on the on-board flash that is private to your app and not visible to users.

`SharedPreferences` is one way of storing data on internal storage.

> Looks like Android system allocates specific amount of space for each application.

No, though they might do this in the future.

> While using shared preferences, my app ran out of memory and threw OutOfMemory Exception

`OutOfMemoryError` refers to heap space (RAM), not storage space.

> If I use internal storage to save this data into files, will this resolve the issue?

Possibly, though it would depend a lot on what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. So, "Internal storage" is not the whole flash memory, but rather it means some 'part' of flash memory dedicated to each application?
Also, @ris8_allo_zen0 said that `SharedPreferences` stores data mainly in RAM, but you didn't mention it stores data in RAM. Which is correct? both RAM and internal storage(on-board flash memory)?

Comment: @starriet: "So, "Internal storage" is not the whole flash memory, but rather it means some 'part' of flash memory dedicated to each application?" -- when the Android SDK refers to "internal storage", it refers to a per-app part of the on-board flash memory. "both RAM and internal storage(on-board flash memory)?" -- `SharedPreferences` are *stored* in internal storage and are *cached* in RAM.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. These concepts can be confusing! thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

- **SharedPreference**: Store private primitive data in key-value pairs. (To store small entries/data)
- **Internal Storage**: Store private data on the device memory. (To store large datasets)

With shared preferences you don't need to handle file IO. for Internal Storage you need handle File IO.

If you have large amount of data you should use Internal Storage. Also you need to avoid storing unnecessary data.

For more info read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html